# get anchor #id urls back with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I've got a fixed menu that uses jquery to smooth scroll to an anchor, that works fine - but when I use the script the anchor link no longer appears in the url. any ideas?

the site is http://www.julianvanmil.com

hears the code I'm using;

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 400);
    });
});
$(function() {
    var bar = $('.logo');
    var top = bar.css('top');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 700) {
            bar.stop().animate({'top' : '35px'}, 300);
        } else {
            bar.stop().animate({'top' : top}, 300);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: We need more info, not just a link to your page.  Please see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event.preventDefault();` is preventing the default action, which is to append the hash to the URL, and then scroll.

Try adding: `location.hash = this.hash` after `event.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the hash with JS...

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 400);
    window.location.hash = "hash";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's works:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 800);
    var target_anchor = this.hash;
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.hash = target_anchor;
    }, 800);
});
```